# What do you call a function that properly remains undefined?

Tags: terminology, naming, functions, null, virtual-functions

### Backstory:

I have subclasses that are supposed to override and define various functions, but not neccessarily all of them. They can't remain purely virtual though for obvious reasons, and so I am going to throw an exception instead.

I just have to name the exception's class, and so it makes sense to use a term that implies that the function is supposed to be remain undefined, as opposed to erroneously undefined.

### Question:

What terminologies imply that a function is properly remaining undefined?

Comment: From a very technical point of view, I'd argue that these methods are _unimplemented_. That being said, it might help to look at this issue from the point of view of the clients of the subclasses. What are their expectations in regards to this? Do they care about the technical details of the functions being unimplemented, or is there a business error you can extract out of there?

Comment: I'd say you have subclasses that aren't subtypes, so perhaps you should be fixing that instead.

Comment: @VincentSavard This actually has to do with card logic. Suppose you have to play a card, and it has to be a trump. The only card you can play is not a trump. Its trump function is called, and now I have to throw an exception. I know there is other logic that I can experss this situation beyond throwing, however I have my reasons to use an exception here.

Comment: @Anon no, you have an empty set of *playable* cards, and you deal with that however the rules say, perhaps by that player losing, or skipping their turn, or whatever

Comment: "*What terminologies imply that a function is properly remaining undefined?*" I would call this, "making Mrs Liskov cry" as what you propose is creating a massive violation of the LSP. A far better solution would be to define multiple interfaces each of which covers a function or set of functions and have the classes only implement applicable interfaces.

Comment: @DavidArno LSP? Mrs Liskov?

Comment: @Anon, LSP = [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and [Barbara Liskov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbara_Liskov) is the creator of that principle. My bad for not clarifying.

Comment: @DavidArno Interesting. I do fall on the side of the criticisms though, considering my base class is abstract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just have to name the exception's class

You don't actually say *which* technology you're using, so you may be missing out on a pre-existing convention or name.
That said ...

.Net has its **NotImplemented**Exception.
Java has a *similar-sounding* **UnsupportedOperation**Exception (although I suspect that one *means* something rather different).

> ... a term that implies that the function is supposed to be remain undefined ...

If you mean that a method **must not** be overridden, then you should be looking at "sealed" or "final" modifiers on the method (if your language has them) that the *compiler* can enforce, rather than leaving it until run-time.

Comment: Its c++. Sealed or Final sound perfect. I've never heard of their modifiers existing in c++ though.

Comment: Depends you the version of C++ that you're using: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824587/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-final-keyword-in-c11-for-functions